# Language switcher is broken when using multiple times : Magento 2.2.1

Tags: language, magento-2.2.1, store-switcher

1. In language switcher when i switch from the default storeview (French in my example) to English, the url changes to: https://example.com/?___store=en
2. Using the language switcher in the header, switch again from English to French, the url changes to: https://example.com/?___store=en?___store=fr and the shop crashes

Answer (score 1):

Go to vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php

**Change this line from:**

```
$requestString = $this->_url->escape(ltrim($this->_request->getRequestString(), '/'));
```

**to:**

```
$requestString = $this->_url->escape(ltrim($this->_request->getOriginalPathInfo(), '/'));
```

You can find this line on **1139**

**This is magento2.2 default issue**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is tracked and solved.

For now, if you want, you could go in

> magento2/app/code/Magento/Store/Model/Store.php (Magento installation by Github)

or

> vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php (Magento installation by composer)

and replace the second row in

> public function getCurrentUrl($fromStore = true)

```
$requestString = $this->_url->escape(ltrim($this->_request->getRequestString(), '/'));
```

with

```
$requestString = $this->_url->escape(
    preg_replace(
        '/\?.*?$/',
        '',
        ltrim($this->_request->getRequestString(), '/')
    )
);
```